# Connecting to MongoDB 3.0 with Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, authentication

I am having problems in using Spring to access MongoDB with credentials.
While without credentials it works like a charme, using them just fails saying

```
    Failed to authenticate to database [yourdatabase], username = [yourusername], password = [x******z]
```

It must be because of new auth default that you can read about in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/

> Changed in version 3.0: SCRAM-SHA-1 is the default mechanism for MongoDB versions beginning with the 3.0 series.

**Question:** Anybody found out a way to use Spring with credentials ? Which version of `spring-data-mongodb` did you use to make the trick ?

Comment: Does your version of spring-data-mongodb work with MongoDB 3.0? What do the release notes say? None of the versions listed on http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/ support MongoDB 3.x.

Comment: @LutzHorn yet, there is a mongo-3 branch in the canonical git repository

Comment: @LutzHorn well 1.7.0.RC1 say something about that, but I still couldn't make it work out ! http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.0.RC1/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-3

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ could you please post the link to the git repo ? It could be useful to take a look

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/tree/mongo-3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a lot of attempts and reading, I found a way to make MongoDB 3.0 work with authentication.

This was a new installation of MongoDB 3.0, no upgrade involved.

I used these maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

having as parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Then in my Configuration file I had

```
/**
 * DB connection Factory
 * 
 * @return a ready to use MongoDbFactory
 */
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {

    // Set credentials      
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUser, databaseName, mongoPass.toCharArray());
    ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(mongoHost, mongoPort);

    // Mongo Client
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress,Arrays.asList(credential)); 

    // Mongo DB Factory
    SimpleMongoDbFactory simpleMongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(
            mongoClient, databaseName);

    return simpleMongoDbFactory;
}

/**
 * Template ready to use to operate on the database
 * 
 * @return Mongo Template ready to use
 */
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
}
```

And finally wherever you have access to the MongoTemplate bean you'll be able to do

```
mongoTemplate.insert(objectToStore, collectionName);
```

Comment: I'm using the above solution but worked out the dependencies a bit different (still inheriting from spring boot starter parent): 

`<properties>
  <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Fowler-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
</properties>`

`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Comment: @Emanuel Hategan, are you saying that you're using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb and not spring-data-mongodb? If so...what other changes did you have to make to get it to work?

Comment: @dreboy yes, I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb which seems to use spring-data-mongodb internally. 
I'm know I was using org.springframework.boot dependency management to keep versions in sync: 
`<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>`
Other than that nothing special AFAIK

Comment: All i needed in addition to the spring-boot-starter-parent dependency was:
                <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 9):

`spring.data.mongodb.host` and `spring.data.mongodb.port` are not supported if you’re using the **Mongo 3.0 Java driver**. In such cases, `spring.data.mongodb.uri` should be used to provide all of the configuration, like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345
```

Just add the `spring.data.mongodb.uri` to your `application.yml` and you'll get the auto configured `MongoDbFactory` and `MongoTemplate`.

Comment: Have googled this simple answer across several resources and found only here! Great thanks, Ali, you've saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

using this versions in your pom:

```
<!-- mongodb java driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring data mongodb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And this configuration in spring:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Seeds -->
    <bean id="mongoSeedListID" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="mongoSeedlID" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoSeedlID" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="host" value="DATABASE_HOST" />
            <constructor-arg type="int" name="port" value="DATABASE_PORT" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Credentials -->
    <bean id="mongoCredentialListID" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="mongoCredentialID" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoCredentialID" class="com.mongodb.MongoCredential">
            <constructor-arg name="mechanism" value = "#{T(com.mongodb.AuthenticationMechanism).SCRAM_SHA_1}" />
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="userName" value="DATABASE_USERNAME" />
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="source" value="DATABASE_SOURCE" />
            <constructor-arg type="char[]" name="password" value="DB_USER_PASS" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MongoClient -->
    <bean id="mongoClientID" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
            <constructor-arg ref="mongoSeedListID" />
            <constructor-arg ref="mongoCredentialID"  />
    </bean>

    <!-- MongoDbFactory -->
    <bean id="simpleMongoDbFactoryID" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoClientID" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="APP_DATABASENAME" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MongoTemplate -->
    <bean id="mongoTemplateID" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="simpleMongoDbFactoryID" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="log4jInitializationID" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:log4j/log4j_test.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

 </beans>
```

With this configuration you only have to inject the MongoTemplate:

```
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("mongoTemplateID")
   private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

This should work fine =)

Comment: Thanks pom configuration help me solve my problem, but i am using this to solve my problem, i can't use other methods `code` @Bean
 @Override
 public MongoClient mongo() throws Exception {
  logger.info("Mongo db config staring");
  
  return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoConfig.getDbUrl()));
 } `code`

Answer (score 2):

Here is xml version to connect MongoDB 3.0.7 with Spring (parameters are passed from a property file):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<mongo:mongo-client host="${mongo.url}" port="${mongo.port}" credentials="${mongo.user}:${mongo.pass}@${mongo.dbname}">
    <mongo:client-options write-concern="NORMAL" />
</mongo:mongo-client>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongo.dbname}"/>
</bean>
```

Then in Java, you get mongoTemplate like this:

```
    @Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public String mongoTest() {

    DBCollection dc = mongoTemplate.getCollection("yourCollection");

    logger.debug("--get collection name=" + dc.getFullName());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two of possibilities how to make Mongodb 3 work with Spring data. Both involve downgrading of authentication schema:

1. start with mongodb 2.x and upgrade to 3.0; works as authentication system stays the same
2. if you have a new installation of mongo 3.0, you can downgrade
   the authentication schema before creating the users.

To downgrade the authentication mechanism:

```
var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"})
schema.currentVersion = 3
db.system.version.save(schema)
```

Or you can even have mixed users, some created with version 5 (that of mongo 3) and some with version 3. Except you will be able to connect (from Spring data) only with users created using version 3.

You could try 3.0 + mongo 3 beta drivers: in general this combination works with "legacy code", but I did not manage to make it work with Spring Data.

Comment: Thanks Normunds , my attempts followed the same path of your last suggestion, to use beta drivers. I needed to upgrade the version of boot started, fix some code, but at last the authentication worked !

Comment: Great, though IMO what you've done is effectively bypassing Spring Data. That was also my conclusion - if I added a similar code I could access mongo 3, but the normal Spring generated repositories did not work. Or do you want to say that Spring Data now picks up your classes instead and works properly?

Comment: That's exactly what I need to find out now, main aim was being able to connect to mongo, bonus mission would be using Spring Data.