# com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on sms to execute command

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to use mongodb with authentication and getting below error:

com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on sms to execute command.

My database name is "sms".

My mongoTemplate bean is like below:

```
<bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
        <constructor-arg name="host" value="${mongodb_host}" />
        <constructor-arg name="port" value="${mongodb_port}" />
</bean>

    <bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
        <constructor-arg name="username" value="${mongodb_username}"> </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg name="password" value="${mongodb_password}" ></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongodb_name}" />
        <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials"/>
    </bean>
```

I used below commands to create a user on mongo.

```
use sms
db.runCommand({ createRole: "myAdmin",
privileges: [
    { resource: { db: "sms", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert", "remove" ] },
  ],
  roles: [
    { role: "readWrite", db: "sms" }
  ],
  writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }
})
db.createUser({"user":"user1","pwd":"admin123","roles":[{"role":"readWrite","db":"sms"}]})

db.auth("user1","admin123") --> gave me 1.
```

I am able to connect to my database and create collection and add document successfully through RoboMongo client but failing through my Java code. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You should use `MongoCredential` instead of `UserCredentials` for authentication. See explanation and examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958789/connecting-to-mongodb-3-0-with-java-spring?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I will check. Thanks.