# Spring data mongodb aggregation is not working with authentication on DB

Tags: aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I am using Spring-data-mongodb to connect with MongoDb from my Java web application. I need to use group by(aggregation in mongoDB) for few Queries.

I am using following code for aggregation.

```html
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate=getMongoTemplate();
 
 public List<SummaryVo> getGroupResult(Appointment appointment, String doctor_id)  {
  System.out.println(mongoTemplate.toString());
  Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("clinic_name").is(appointment.getClinic_name()).and("appointment_date_time")
               .gte(appointment.getAppointment_date_time()).lte(appointment.getEnd_appointment_date_time())),
    group(doctor_id).count().as("total"),
    project("total").and(doctor_id).previousOperation(),
    sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "total")

   );
   //Convert the aggregation result into a List
   AggregationResults<SummaryVo> groupResults
    = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "appointment", SummaryVo.class);
   return groupResults.getMappedResults();
  }

public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate(){
  
  final UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials("admin", "admin123");
  final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new Mongo(),"my-database", userCredentials);
  return mongoTemplate;
 }
```

Initially I Autowired the Mongotemplate directly and it was working fine.
Now I have added authentication on My mongoDb and my all other queries are working except this aggregate method.

I am trying to find a way to solve it. Thats why I tried using mongoTemplate with user credential so that it can authenticate the DB. But still its not working.I am getting belo mentioned error in tomcat log:-

```html
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on cms-database to execute command { aggregate: "appointment", pipeline: [ { $match:
```

Kindly help me to find a solution for this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you should use MongoCredentials for the authentification like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28981425/2055854

Comment: Thanks for help.. that answer solved my problem