# Unable to create MongoClient bean in springboot from appContext.xml: credential type conversion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I have an existing Java library that uses MongoDB Spring. The library contains applcationContext.xml and config.properties files that configures it to connect to a remote MongoDB instance and does so correctly.

I am trying to use this library in a SpringBoot application, using the exact same two files, but SpringBoot seems to have trouble wiring up the MongoDB client, exception below.  Here is my application class/configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"applicationContext.xml"})
public class MySpringBootApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

Here is the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mongodb.MongoCredential[]' for property 'credentials'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mongodb.MongoCredential' for property 'credentials[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at org.MyCompany.MySpringBootApplication.main(MySpringBootApplication.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mongodb.MongoCredential[]' for property 'credentials'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mongodb.MongoCredential' for property 'credentials[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:605)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:617)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1577)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1536)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mongodb.MongoCredential' for property 'credentials[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
    ... 26 more
```

The applicationContext.xml has the following config for mongoDB:

```
<context:property-placeholder
  location="classpath:config.properties" />
<mongo:mongo-client 
  id="mongo" 
  replica-set="${mongo.replica.set}" 
  credentials="${mongo.credentials}" />
```

Where config.properties has the values for mongo.credentials.

I have used spring-boot-mongodb and added the configuration and connected successfully, but there are many dozens of other beans configured in that file that I am not sure how to wire up in SpringBoot that depend on the mongoClient. It would be much faster (I hope) to figure out how to tell SpringBoot to create the MongoCredential correctly.

Do I need to implement a StringToMongoCredentialConverter? Or am I doomed to pull everything in applicationContext.xml to some Java config class?

Using spring-boot 1.5.4, spring-core 4.3.9, spring-data-mongo 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer in [Connecting to MongoDB 3.0 with Java Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958789/connecting-to-mongodb-3-0-with-java-spring), ended up replacing the  element with the following:

```
<!-- Seeds -->
<bean id="mongoSeedListID" class="java.util.ArrayList">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <ref bean="mongoSeedlID" />
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoSeedlID" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="host" value="DATABASE_HOST" />
        <constructor-arg type="int" name="port" value="DATABASE_PORT" />
</bean>

<!-- Credentials -->
<bean id="mongoCredentialListID" class="java.util.ArrayList">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <ref bean="mongoCredentialID" />
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoCredentialID" class="com.mongodb.MongoCredential">
        <constructor-arg name="mechanism" value = "#{T(com.mongodb.AuthenticationMechanism).SCRAM_SHA_1}" />
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="userName" value="DATABASE_USERNAME" />
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="source" value="DATABASE_SOURCE" />
        <constructor-arg type="char[]" name="password" value="DB_USER_PASS" />
</bean>

<!-- MongoClient -->
<bean id="mongoClientID" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoSeedListID" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoCredentialID"  />
</bean>
```

and it worked!